# Show div when radio button is checked

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, radio-button

I've been trying for ages to solve this problem but I have been unable to. What i'd like to do is have a certain div show on the webpage when a certain radio button is selected. I have been able to do this when the form is submitted but i'd rather not have to rely on submitting it.

```
<form name="options" action="index.php" method="post">
    <input type="radio" name="option" value="True"/>True<br>
</form>
<div id="show-1" style="display:none;">
    <form action="1.php" method="post">
        <input type="date" name="date"/><br/>
        <select name="people">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>
            <option>6</option>
            <option>7</option>
            <option>8</option>
            <option>9</option>
            <option>10</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name$='option']").click(function(){
    var radio_value = $(this).val();
    if(radio_value =='True') {
        $("#show-1").show("slow");
        }
    });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You would have to use AJAX to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this **easily** via jQuery.

```js
$("[value='input1'").click(function() {
  $(".show").show()
});
```

```css
.show {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="radio" value="input1"><label for="input1">input</label><br>
  <input type="radio" value="input2"><label for="input2">input</label><br>
  <input type="radio" value="input3"><label for="input3">input</label><br>
  <input type="radio" value="input4"><label for="input4">input</label><br>
  <input type="radio" value="input5"><label for="input5">input</label><br>
  <input type="radio" value="input6"><label for="input6">input</label><br>
</form>
<div class="show">
  hello world!
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this is what you want

```
var isChecked = $(this).prop("checked");
if(isChecked)
    $("#show-1").show("slow");
```

Comment: You should always use braces in if statements, as IE doesn't support "loose" ones.

Comment: Thanks! I'll fix that

Answer (score 0):

You check it based on the jquery [is checked](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/), rather than .val

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("input[name$='option']").click(function(){
        var radio_value = $(this).is(':checked');
        if(radio_value) {
            $("#show-1").show("slow");
            }
        });
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/owb2bkw2/4/

Answer (score 0):

Plain JS solution with fade animation handled via [CSS keyframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%40keyframes):

```js
document.querySelector("input[name$='option']").addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    document.querySelector("#show-1").style.display = 'block';
    document.querySelector("#show-1").classList.add('animate');
  }
})
```

```css
.animate {
  opacity: 1;
  animation: fade 1s;
}

@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="options" action="index.php" method="post">
  <input type="radio" name="option" />True<br>
</form>
<div id="show-1" style="display:none;">
  <form action="1.php" method="post">
    <input type="date" name="date" /><br/>
    <select name="people">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
      <option>6</option>
      <option>7</option>
      <option>8</option>
      <option>9</option>
      <option>10</option>
    </select>
  </form>
</div>
```